# How to update a NULL foreign key and create a new row within another table referencing the same key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables,`users` and `hubs`. Once the user creates an account, my backend will make a new row within the `users table` (filling in all columns of the row except the `hubID` column as it is not known yet).

Once the user has signed up, they are greeted with a setup screen, to which where they will obtain a `hubID` from an external product that the app connects to. I want to then update their `user row` inside the `users table` and add the `hubID` to their row (which is currently null) AND at the same time add a new row inside the `hubs table` where the `primary key` will be the hubID (as it will always be unique).

The `Users table` has the `foreign key` to reference a row inside the `hubs table`.

Users table

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UserID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Username | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Email    | varchar(25) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Password | varchar(50) | NO   |     |         |                |
| hubID    | varchar(50) | YES  |     |         | foreign_key    |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Hubs Table

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| hubID     | varchar(50)| NO   | PRI |         |                |
| isSetup   | BOOLEAN    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| SWVersion | DOUBLE(2,3)| NO   |     | 0.1     |                |
| dateAdded | TIMESTAMP  | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

At the moment, I am using the query:

```
update users set hubID = 'hub123' where userID = '1';
```

to add the new hubID to the relevant row inside the `users table`. But I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_hubs1` FOREIGN KEY (`hubID`) REFERENCES `hubs` (`hubID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I don't know how one would update a foreign key AND add a new row within a different table with the same key so they both represent each other. My model at the moment would work if I knew the hubID when creating the `user's row`, but that simply is impossible for my design.

This is the script:

`users table`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`users` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `hubID` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  INDEX `fk_users_hubs1_idx` (`hubID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_hubs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`hubID`)
    REFERENCES `database`.`hubs` (`hubID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`hubs table`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`hubs` (
  `hubID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `isSetup` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `hubSWVersion` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.1,
  `dateAdded` DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`hubID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: *I am getting this error* Before asigning `update users set hubID = 'hub123' ...` you must insert `'hub123'` value into `hubs` table (or ensure that it exists already). PS. You show `database.hubs` but refer to `centreCore.hubs`.

Comment: @Akina Sorry, it was an old script, the only database being used is called `database`, I've updated the script to show that.

Comment: @Akina That was my error, I needed to add the` hubID` into the `hubs table` (or at least check) before updating my `users table`, would you like to add it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `user.username` to be unique also. Anyway, I am assuming it is. Even if it isn't there is a remedy I will describe later. The solution is simply doing inserts in the correct order. For example:

```
insert into users(username, email, password) values('Booboo', 'Booboo@nowhere.atall', 'password');
insert into hubs(hubID, isSetup, dateAdded) values('hubBooboo', 1, now());
update users set hubId = 'hubBooboo' where username = 'Booboo';
```

[See db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6TBrbsvxuLuEkmvka7EW82/0)

I am assuming that because `username` columns are unique I can do the last update by using the known `username`. But even if that assumption is not correct, you can always retrieve the last inserted autoinsert key (i.e. column `userId`) with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and then use column `userId` in the where clause.